# How To Maintain Rotation Between Front & Back Camera Images And Conversions To CIImage, CGImage, and UIImage

Tags: objective-c, uiimage, core-graphics, avfoundation, quartz-graphics

I'm doing something I'm sure thousands of apps do: take pictures and apply filters and crop effects.

The whole thing has become a LOT more complicated than I would have thought and my code has become quite messy as I try to maintain the proper image orientation. I would love to here from any AVFoundation or Core Graphics experts on this issue.

So my app does the following:
1. Presents a live feed on the iPad
2. Lets them switch to front or back camera
3. Lets them take a picture
4. Lets them add filters to the picture (by picking from pre-existing thumbnails)

Rotation issue #1:
When I take a picture with the front camera

```
 if(imageDataSampleBuffer !=NULL)
        {
            NSData *imageData = [AVCaptureStillImageOutput jpegStillImageNSDataRepresentation:imageDataSampleBuffer];
            _capturedImage = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
            if(!_faceCameraAway)//flip image
            {
                _capturedImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:_capturedImage.CGImage scale:1.0 orientation:UIImageOrientationLeftMirrored];
            }
            [self loadEditPhoto];//have to put it here otherwise load edit gets called out of ordere
        }
```

I need to check if its the camera on the front or I get a flipped image. So the live feed of a front facing camera presents a mirror of the actual raw image it takes. I can only see this getting worse as I tackle landscape vs portrait...

Rotation Issue #2:
When the app lets them apply filters it supplies a UIScrollView with UIImageView previews of the filters they can apply. When it actually applies the image change (i.e swaps in the filtered image) to the filtered version though, again I need to check for rotations and camera facings otherwise things gets flipped. Here is the code I need to use to fix the issue

```
-(void)swapDisplayImage:(UIGestureRecognizer*)tap
{
    CIImage* newImage = [(UIImageView*)tap.view image].CIImage;
    //need to rotate 90*, orientation is not working so the fix below is required !!! ALSO front facing cameras have ADDITIONAL REQUIREMENTS so need to test case, would like a better solution down the road
    CGAffineTransform transform;
    if(_faceCameraAway)
    {
        transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(-M_PI_2);
        _capturedImageView.image = [UIImage imageWithCIImage:newImage scale:1.0 orientation:[(UIImageView*)tap.view image].imageOrientation];
    }else
    {
        transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(-M_PI);
        _capturedImageView.image = [UIImage imageWithCIImage:newImage scale:1.0 orientation:UIImageOrientationDown];//mirrored does not work in this case it has to be down
    }
    _capturedImageView.transform = transform;
}
```

Caveats:
Preserving the orientation when creating a UIImage with UImage.image.imageOrientation does not work. I will literally see "orientation 3", apply the filter image, then see "orientation 3" again in the logs. So even though it SAYS they have the same orientation, because I converted them to a CIImage, things got scrambled.

**Ultimate Question:** Is it supposed to be this messy? Do I need to check tons and tons of factors constantly every time I need to move between image filters, do a crop, or apply filters? Or, hopefully, is there a simpler way to keep track of orientation once and no matter what I do (apply a filter, or use a front camera and convert between UIImage, CIImage and CGImage multiple times) that I can properly orient the image consistently (without having to factor in dozens of special cases with each modification?)?

Comment: On issue #1 _"when I take a picture with the front camera I get a flipped image"_ that is intentional, take a picture w/Apple's camera and then look at the output in the Photos app, its reversed.  On issue #2, UIImage<->CGimage<->UIImage<->GPUImage, _especially_ with cropping and rotating is an ordeal, do yourself a favor and integrate (or build) a library that helps manage that stuff, UIImage+Resize is a nice start http://git.io/g6cTFw.  I've spent the last 3 years on photo apps, its never easy :)

Comment: So it is mess eh! Thanks for the tips